# add a value randomly to a matrix

Tags: r, random

How can I randomly add a value to a matrix?

say I have:

```
mat <- matrix(0, 10, 10)
v = 5
```

how can I add randomly v to mat, 2 positions at a time? The output should look like this after a single iteration:

```
out
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[2,]    5    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    5    0    0    0    0     0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[10,]   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

After another iteration, mat should have 2 more positions filled with the value in 'v'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `?sample` to randomly index your matrix:

```
idx <- sample(length(mat), size=2)
mat[idx] <- mat[idx] + v
```